# How to get >=85% accuracy on 3-class classification task

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, accuracy

Now I am solving the problem of 3-class classification (in the task you need to understand who is in the picture - a panda, a cat or a dog). The dataset consists of 3000 images. To solve the problem, I use a slightly modified VGG architecture:[image]

After 200 epochs I got the following quality:[image]

In the problem, it is required to rich >= 85% quality on validation set. To be honest, I have no any special thoughts yet. Can you please give advice on what to change / add / remove in the neural network architecture in order to achieve the desired result? I wan to note, that I am already using data augmentation.

Comment: Maybe you could try to add one more dense layer at the end. Going from 4096 neurons to 3 looks a bit fast.

Comment: That is personally what I would try first. Than I would also decrease the learning rate a bit just because it looks to go very fast to the minimum but not sure if this improves anything.

Comment: Data augmentation is quite broad -- I feel like there's specific types of augmentations that might be most suited to your problem. You can think of data augmentation as a way to "anticipate" invariants in your data. Also, hyperparameter sweeps (esp. learning rate, regularization parameter) can help with this as well. Unfortunately, there aren't a ton of rigorous theoretical results on deep neural networks, but these heuristics can help sometimes.

Comment: Exactly that is why the author should tell us how what are the results when following suggestions :)